# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'extensions' of undefined. (GraphQL)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graph

I am using GraphQL along with MERNG and I am getting the following error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'extensions' of undefined. Please help me out. I also reinstalled graphql. This is the line where the error occurs: setErrors(err.graphQLErrors[0].extensions.exception.errors);

This is my Register.js file:

```js
import React, {
  useState
} from 'react'
import {
  Button,
  Form
} from 'semantic-ui-react'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import {
  useMutation
} from '@apollo/react-hooks'

function Register() {
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    username: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    confirmPassword: ''
  })

  const onChange = (event) => {
    setValues({ ...values,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  }

  const [addUser, {
    Loading
  }] = useMutation(REGISTER_USER, {
    update(proxy, result) {
      console.log(result);
    },
    onError(err) {
      console.log(err.graphQLErrors[0].extensions.exception.errors);
      setErrors(err.graphQLErrors[0].extensions.exception.errors);
    },
    variables: values
  })

  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    addUser();
  }



  return ( <
    div className = "form-container" >
    <
    Form onSubmit = {
      onSubmit
    }
    noValidate >
    <
    h1 > Register < /h1> <
    Form.Input label = "Username"
    placeholder = "Username"
    name = 'username'
    type = "text"
    value = {
      values.username
    }
    onChange = {
      onChange
    }
    /> <
    Form.Input label = "Email"
    placeholder = "Email"
    name = 'email'
    type = "email"
    value = {
      values.email
    }
    onChange = {
      onChange
    }
    /> <
    Form.Input label = "Password"
    placeholder = "Password"
    name = 'password'
    type = "password"
    value = {
      values.password
    }
    onChange = {
      onChange
    }
    /> <
    Form.Input label = "Confirm Password"
    placeholder = "Confirm Password"
    name = 'confirmPassword'
    type = "password"
    value = {
      values.confirmPassword
    }
    onChange = {
      onChange
    }
    /> <
    Button type = "submit"
    primary >
    Register <
    /Button> <
    /Form> {
      Object.keys(errors).length > 0 && ( <
        div className = "ui error message" >
        <
        ul className = "list" > {
          Object.values(errors).map(value => ( <
            li key = {
              value
            } > {
              value
            } < /li>
          ))
        } <
        /ul> <
        /div>
      )
    } <
    /div>
  )
}

const REGISTER_USER = gql `
    mutation register(
        $username: String!
        $email: String!
        $password: String!
        $confirmPassword: String!
    ){
        register(
            RegisterInput: {
                username: $username
                email: $email
                password: $password
                confirmPassword: $confirmPassword
            }
        ){
            id email username createdAt token
        }
    }
`

export default Register;
```

Comment: what is the output of console.log(err.graphQLErrors[0].extensions.exception.errors); ?

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'extensions' of undefined
    at onError (Register.js:24)
    at MutationData.onMutationError (MutationData.ts:143)
    at MutationData.ts:77

Answer (score 2):

It suggests clealry that `err.graphQLErrors[0]` is undefined ,if you dont want that undefined error you can do something like this:

```
setErrors(err&&err.graphQLErrors[0]?err.graphQLErrors[0].extensions.exception.errors:{});
```

Comment: It shows the following error : Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: remove setErrors(err&&err.graphQLErrors[0]?err.graphQLErrors[0].extensions.exception.errors:null); and simply do a console.log of the error and tell me what you get ?

Comment: like this:console.log(err&&err.graphQLErrors[0]?err.graphQLErrors[0]:"foo")

Comment: it returns foo in console

Comment: what is the output of : console.log(err?err:"foo")

Comment: Error: Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400 and undefined on the next line

Comment: that means there is some issue in fetching your error,the desired type that you are wanting you are not getting it.So you further need to debug it that why you are not getting it.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `setErrors`
from

```
setErrors(err.graphQLErrors[0].extensions.exception.errors);
```

to

```
setErrors(err.graphQLErrors[0].extensions.errors);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `console.log(err);` and see what kind of error it is. Maybe it is a network error.